# How can I restrict the event that must be initiated the request from the web in MVC,I must prevent the request from winform or other client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

My mvc website have a request to my controller action called `GetStudent`.When user click the search button in the web page `StudentPage`,I will use ajax get method to my action which I have verify the  access to this method. If the method is `post`,I can use `AntiForgeryToken()`,but now my method is `get`,so I have to change it to post method.How can I use another way to prevent the request from winform or other client .I want that only when user log in and visit the web page `StudentPage`,the acthion will response the search result.

Comment: There simply is no way to guarantee this, since a client is free to pretend to be a web browser all they want and give the same responses a web browser would give.  AntiForgeryToken is only used to prevent a specific kinds of forgery requests, and probably not what you are thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erik is right.However, If your question is looked from different perspective, it seems like you are looking for some sort of Authentication mechanism. Are you sure you are not looking for Authentication?

If that is the case, go for looking into FormsAuthentication and in your action method, check whether request is authenticated request.

Answer (score 0):

In web browser you can add a common change method instead of changing every ajax get method to post method.In your web server,you can get the `Request.UrlReferrer`.

Comment: A non-browser client can add a referrer header and bypass this very easily.